# Remove all padding from a div

Tags: html, css

I am currently fighting with a responsive Two Column Layout. The problem being that I can adjust the padding on the left and right of the divs but not the top and bottom. I've tried manually setting the padding-top for every element in the html and nothing is working.

I've fought with it for an hour at this point, so I am now reaching out for help. Code is below, I've also attached visual examples of what I need. (Ignore the plain text ugliness, I'm not placing it on the site itself until I have it fixed.)

This is the CSS.

```
.TwoColumnRow * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.list_2Column {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.list_2Column ul {
top-padding: 0px;
}

.TwoColumnRow :after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 450px) {
    .list_2Column {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

This is the HTML.

```
<h2>What is the Employee Wellness Program?</h2>
<p>Our Employee Wellness Program assists businesses, non-profits, and their employees to navigate workplace and personal challenges through educational and supportive counseling. Our program has a strong mental health component which can stand alone or be used with a company’s existing wellness initiative. Research shows employee wellness services can benefit organizations by:</p>

<div class="TwoColumnRow">
<div class="list_2Column" style="background-color:#ededed">
<ul>
<li>Increasing productivity
<li>Decreasing absenteeism and lost revenue
<li>Improving morale and loyalty
</ul>
  </div>
  <div class="list_2Column" style="background-color:#cccccc">
  <ul>
<li>Teaching new skills
<li>Providing resources and referrals
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I need it to look like:

[image]

What it currently looks like:

[image]

Comment: Why don't you close you're `<li>`'s?

Comment: Your CSS is invalid and full of typos.

Comment: That's how it came from dev team. I've never seen it make a difference to add closing tags for <li> but if there's a reason they need them I'll add them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.list_2Column ul {
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    margin-top: 3px;
}
```

You can change this to 0px if you want absolutely no padding

Comment: This fixed everything, thank you! I can't believe I forgot to set the margins though, *shameface*

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing like `top-margin:0`. Try this code.

```
.list_2Column ul {
  padding-top: 0px;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Add** `margin-top: 0;` and `margin-bottom: 0;` to:

```
.list_2Column ul {
  top-padding: 0px;
}
```